# I can use local Storage in NextJS (redux-thunk)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, local-storage

I cant use local Storage  in file Store.js.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

in Store.js

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import {
  productDetailsReducer,
  productsReducer,
} from "./reducers/productsReducer";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducers/cartsReducer";


const reducer = combineReducers({
  products: productsReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
});

let initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
      : [],
  }
};


const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

Window is not defined in next.js because it renders in server, you need to check for the window object before using localStorage an example of check will be:

```js
 let initialState = {
    cart: {
      cartItems:  typeof window !== 'undefined' && localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
        : [],
    }
  };
```

If you want more efficient way of creating store, follow the example provided by next.js:
[Redux presist example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-redux-persist/store.js)